# uniform boundedness and pointwise convergence

Tags: metric-spaces, pointwise-convergence

Let   { f n : A → ( X , d )│n ϵ N } be a sequence of  bounded functions from a non empty set  A  to a metric space ( X , d ) and let   f n  converges point wise to a bounded function
f  : A → ( X , d ) . Then is it true that the sequence ( f n ) is uniformly bounded. If  it is true then how to prove and if not then can we find a counter example. Please note that point wise convergence does not imply uniform convergence and hence does not imply uniform boundedness. Thanks in advance for any help.

I know that the converse of the above statement is true that is “ if the sequence of functions { f n : A → ( X , d )│n ϵ N } is  uniformly bounded and converges point wise to a function  f  : A → ( X , d ) , then the function  f  : A → ( X , d ) is bounded”.

Answer (score 1):

Take, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}f_n\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}n&\text{ if }x=n\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then each $f_n$ is bounded and the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwise to the null function, which is bounded. However, the set $\{f_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is *not* unformly bounded.